# Titlesec and uppercase

Tags: titlesec

If I compile this code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering}
   {\em{\MakeUppercase\chaptertitlename~\ORDINALstring{chapter}}}
   {20pt}
   {\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
   {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Title of Chapter One}

\section{Title of First Section}
\lipsum{1}

\section{Title of Second Section}
\lipsum{2}

\chapter{Title of Chapter Two}

\section{Title of First Section}
\lipsum{1}

\section{Title of Second Section}
\lipsum{2}

\end{document}
```

I obtain the desired result. But if I apply the Italian language with babel, the result becomes very curious because I see, for all chapters, not `Capitolo Primo`, `Capitolo secondo` and so on, but in all cases `Capitolo novantaduesimo` [= Chapter ninety-second].
Am I doing something wrong or is there anything wrong with one command or package?
Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but that's a problem with `fmtcount` that uses wrongly `itnumpar`. Change `\em{\MakeUppercase\chaptertitlename~\ORDINALstring{chapter}}` into `\itshape\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename~\Ordinalem{chapter}}`

Comment: thanks. @egreg is always foolproof about LaTeX ... Now I see the bug is known (https://github.com/nlct/fmtcount/issues/37), but unsolved since 2018